# How to declare dynamic TypeScript object name to be used in onClick event?

Tags: javascript, razor, model-view-controller, typescript

let's say I have a TypeScript object that I declare somewhere on my view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myTSObject = Module.CustomClass('#someId');
    myISObject.bind();
</script>
```

Now I need to handle a click even from somewhere inside the element holding the `<script>` tag:

```
<div id="thisDiv">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var myTSObject = Module.CustomClass('#thisDiv');
        myISObject.bind();
    </script>
    <button onClick="myISObject.handleClick()" />
</div>
```

So far so good, but what if I use the above `<div>...</div>` block as a template so it when my view is generated, it looks like this:

```
<div id="thisDiv">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var myTSObject = Module.CustomClass('#thisDiv');
        myISObject.bind();
    </script>
    <button onClick="myISObject.handleClick()" />
</div>
<div id="thatDiv">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var myTSObject = Module.CustomClass('#thatDiv');
        myISObject.bind();
    </script>
    <button onClick="myISObject.handleClick()" />
</div>
```

This will understandably fail because now the second myISObject overides the first one. But due to the `<div>...</div>` block being a template, I can't hardcode the JS variable name. How to handle this accordingly?

Comment: `myTSObject` VS `myISObject` - are they supposed to be the same ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set this at the top of your page:

```
var divnumber=0;
```

then use this for each div:

```
divnumber++;
window['myISObject' + divnumber] = ...
```